# Как правильно создать локальную коллекцию для запроса с оператором TABLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Участник [@максим ильин](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/265568/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b8%d0%bd) спрашивал [в этой теме (была удалена автором)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303660).

Пытаюсь создать локальную коллекцию с элементами ключ-значение, чтобы потом её использовать в SQL запросе с `TABLE` оператором как обычную таблицу.

Пробую так:

```
declare
    type tabtype is table of maptype index by binary_integer;
    tab tabtype;
    type valuesarr is table of varchar2 (16);
    res valuesarr;
begin
    select t.key, t.val bulk collect into tab
    from (
        select 'key'||rownum key, 'val'||rownum val
        from dual connect by level<=3) t;
        
    select val bulk collect into res
    from table (tab);
    dbms_output.put_line ('count of values='||res.count);
end;
/
```

Но получаю следующую ошибку:

> Error report -
> ORA-06550: Строка 13, столбец 17:
> PLS-00382: выражение неправильного типа
> ORA-06550: Строка 13, столбец 10:
> PL/SQL: ORA-22905: невозможно получить доступ к строкам элемента, не являющегося вложенной таблицей

Почему эта ошибка, и как правильно объявить локальную коллекцию?

Answer (score 3):

Эта ошибка возникает, если SQL парсеру неизвестен тип данных, переданной ему переменной связывания.

Локальные коллекции, включая их элементы, *должны быть заранее* объявлены в *спецификации* пакета. При компиляции пакета, PL/SQL компилятор неявно создаст структуры, аналогичные типам данных создаваемых явно выражениями `CREATE TYPE [...]`. Эти структуры будут известны в SQL контексте во время парсинга запроса. Так как анонимный блок выполняется единоразово и не имеет имени, то никаках дополнительных структур для локальных коллекций и их элементов PL/SQL компилятор не создаёт.

Воспроизводимый пример, как нужно сделать:

```
create or replace package pack as
    type rectype is record (key varchar2(8), val varchar2 (16));
    type tabtype is table of rectype index by binary_integer;
end;
/

declare 
    tab pack.tabtype;
    type valuesarr is table of varchar2 (16);
    res valuesarr;
begin
    select t.key, t.val bulk collect into tab
    from (
        select 'key'||rownum key, 'val'||rownum val
        from dual connect by level<=3) t;

    select val bulk collect into res 
    from table (tab);
    dbms_output.put_line ('count of values='||res.count);
end;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

> count of values=3